# Android webview scroll does not work after change the current activity and return back

Tags: android, webview, scroll

I'm new to android. I created an application with two activities. In the first activity I have a `webview` and in second activity there is settings. after I worked with `webview` for a while and go to settings activity then comeback to first activity, `webview` scroll get stuck and does not work anymore.
this is first activity xml including `webview`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap">

            <myPackage.common.ui.browser_toolbar.BrowserToolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/toolbar_border"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.05"
                android:progressTint="@color/progressBar"
                android:visibility="gone"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/web_tab_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:context=".tab.TabActivity">

        <myPackage.common.ui.scroll_aware_refresh_layout.ScrollAwareRefreshLayout
            android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/web_view_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </myPackage.common.ui.scroll_aware_refresh_layout.ScrollAwareRefreshLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/suggestions_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/web_view_full_screen_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/fullScreenBackground"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I create `webview` and append it to `web_view_container` in Java as below:

```
public class TabActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Toolbar toolbar = this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        this.webView = new WebView(this);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            Bundle bundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle("web_view");
            this.webView.restoreState(bundle);
        }
        ViewGroup webViewContainer = this.findViewById(R.id.web_view_container);
        webViewContainer.addView(this.webView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        this.webView.saveState(bundle);
        outState.putBundle("web_view", bundle);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle("web_view");
        this.webView.restoreState(bundle); 
    }
}
```

What should I do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code are looks like correct. But try to remove  the `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` attribute from the  This attribute can interfere with the state restoration process. And in your TabActivity, override the onBackPressed() method and remove the WebView from its parent container before finishing the activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    ViewGroup webViewContainer = findViewById(R.id.web_view_container);
    webViewContainer.removeView(webView);
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```